# .exe has stopped working (Cprogramming)

Tags: c

I am running this program and keep getting an error after I input my name

"program1.exe has stopped working"

have no idea why any help?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

void create();
//void edit();
//void delete();
int main()
{
    char choice;
    printf("\n\t\t **********************\n\n");
    printf("\n\t\t Train Booking Application\n");
    printf("\n\t\t **********************\n\n");
    printf("Select 1 to create a booking,\tSelect 2 to Edit booking,\tSelect 3 to Delete a booking\n");
    scanf("%d",&choice);
    if (choice == 1){
        create();
    }

    return 0;   
}

void create(){
    char Fname,Sname;
    printf("Please enter your First name:\n");
    scanf ("%s",Fname);
    printf("Please enter your Second name:\n");


}
```

Comment: I gusss you input a name that is not a character, character only accepts a single value. try using string as a type.

Comment: There is an inconsistency in `scanf("%d",&choice)`: you scan an integer number, but provide storage only for one character. Same with `scanf ("%s",Fname)`.

Comment: `char Fname, Sname;`... `char` is just that. One character. You need a whole array of characters to form a string. Do a google search on `"strings in C"` or read your C manual. And `scanf("%s", Fname)` attempts to interpret the contents of `Fname` as a pointer to a string. That's bad. You need to study the manual page for `scanf`.

Comment: yh i changed the second part thanks, and ive tried to input strings,numbers,characters but am still getting the same error

Comment: You get the same error probably because you have the same fundamental problem: you're treating something as a pointer (a memory address in C) that should not be so. This is not a good question for Stackoverflow because it indicates you need to go back and learn C fundamentals. This is not a basic language tutorial site.

Comment: oh ok thanks for the help

Comment: Whatever compiler you're using, *turn up the warnings*. For MSVC, compile with `/Wall`, for gcc/clang/pgcc/icc/suncc/xlc, `-Wall`. Pretty much any compiler should be able to catch this sort of problem and warn you about it at compile time.

Comment: You claim the posted code is C, however, it contains the statement: `#include <iostream>`  which is a C++ header file.  Strongly suggest removing that statement,.'

Comment: when writing a prototype for a function that has not parameters, place `void` between the parens  I.E. `void create();` should be: `void create( void );`

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%d",&choice);`  The variable `choice` is declared as `char`, but the input/format specifier `%d` is expecting a `int*`  Suggest using `%c`

Comment: this: `if (choice == 1){` would be better written as: `switch( choice ) { case 1:  create();  break;  case 2: ; break;  case 3: ; break;  default: puts( "invalid menu selection, try again" ); break; }`

Comment: when calling any of the scanf() family of functions, 1) always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful. I.E. use something similar to `if( 1 != scanf("%c",&choice) ) { fprintf( stderr, "scanf for 'choice' failed" ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`  2) when using the '%s' or '%[...]' format specifiers, always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer, because those format specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input.  This also avoids any possibility of buffer overflow, which is undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event

Comment: this declaration: `char Fname,Sname;`  declares two variables, each of which is 1 char long.  Given the call: `scanf ("%s",Fname);`  they should each be (at least) 3 bytes long, and preferably longer than the longest expected name I.E. `char Fname[30];  char Sname[30];  Then the call to scanf would be: `if( 1 != scanf( "%29s", Fname ) ) {  // handle error and exit }`

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0):

char is used to read one character. Use string instead.
%d is used for reading integers but you defined . Either use

```
int choice;
```

or use

```
scanf("%s", &choice);
```

try to use a switch for your selection too

```
switch(choice){
case 1:
create();
break;

case default:
//default statement(s)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please pay attention to the compiler warnings. It will discover problems for you. Suggestion for improvements in the program comments:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//#include <iostream> // C++ include, not needed!

void create();

int main()
{
    int choice; // changed to int to match scanf("%d", char is to small to hold an `int`

    printf("\n\t\t **********************\n\n");
    printf("\n\t\t Train Booking Application\n");
    printf("\n\t\t **********************\n\n");
    printf("Select 1 to create a booking,\tSelect 2 to Edit booking,\tSelect 3 to Delete a booking\n");

    scanf("%d", &choice);

     switch (choice){        // switch is a better choice than nested ifs
         case 1:
             create();
         break;

         default:
         printf("not implemented yet...\n");
         break;
     }

    return 0;   
}

void create(){
    char Fname[256],Sname[256];  // changed to arrays to match scanf ("%s"
    // char Fname, Sname with %s would destroy memory 
    printf("Please enter your First name:\n");
    scanf ("%s",Fname);
    printf("Please enter your Second name:\n");
    scanf ("%s",Sname);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As char just store one character and your name is longer than that, try using ***char Fname[]***, for storing your entire name.